# If Formula in excel for time range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have set of data, trying put a if formula for date range (ref attached image)

[image]

Comment: `P3<$R$1>$S$1` and `P3>U1<V1` don't work in Excel. You need to use `AND`, e.g. `AND(P3<$R$1,$R$1>$S$1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the second half of the formula isn't absolute:

=IF(P3<$R$1>$S$1,O3-1,IF(**P3>U1<V1**,O3))

Also, as BigBen said, you will need to use the AND function. Try this:

```
=IF(AND($R$1<P3,P3<$S$1),O3-1,IF(AND($U$1<P3,P3<$V$1),O3))
```

See this image:
[image: Please see this image]

I also note that you do not have anything entered if the second expression is false.
Say if you wish this to be O3 + 1 (i.e. the next day) then the formula should be this:

```
=IF(AND($R$1<P3,P3<$S$1),O3-1,IF(AND($U$1<P3,P3<$V$1),O3,O3+1))
```

I would also like to note that Excel is 24-hour format, so the above parameter of 11:59:59 is 11:59:59am, not 11:59:59pm, which would be 23:59:59.

Hope this helps!